# PyQt5 Reset Translation to source language

Tags: python, pyqt5

How can I switch back to the source language after translating the GUI?

```
def ChangeLanguage(self, row):
    self.ui.trans = QTranslator(self)
    if row > 0:
        self.ui.trans.load("GUI/Language/hu.qm")
        QApplication.instance().installTranslator(self.ui.trans)
        self.ui.retranslateUi(self)
    else:
        # Default language or Source language
        pass
```

Comment: [`removeTranslator()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#removeTranslator)?

Comment: How do I have to call the remove Translation?
`
        else:
            # Default language or Source language
            QApplication.instance().removeTranslator(self)
            self.ui.retranslateUi(self)
`

Comment: You should *first* check if the row is valid, *then*, if it is, create the reference to the translator and install it, otherwise remove the previously one (if it exists).

Comment: If it worked, I suggest you to add your own answer by clicking the "Answer your question" button, providing a brief explanation and a basic code to show how you did it.